# WSS Ergodic Process with Power Spectrum

Tags: signal-analysis, power-spectral-density, random, ergodic

I was given a WSS ergodic process $x(t)$ with power spectrum :

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
       G_x(f) &=&1−\left|\frac{f}{B}\right| &\mbox{for } |f|<B\\
       G_x(f) &=& 0 & \mbox{ elsewhere}
\end{array}
$$
and first order probability density function is uniform in the range $[−A, A]$. 
How do I evaluate $A$?

It's not a home work but it was a question asked in my exam which I failed.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compute the power of the process from its power spectrum as well as from its PDF. Equating the two gives you a relation between the constants $A$ and $B$. More specifically you get

$$\int_{-B}^BG_x(f)df=\frac{1}{2A}\int_{-A}^Ax^2dx$$

If I'm not mistaken this should give $A=\sqrt{3B}$.